# I can't find the location of elements I want

Tags: python, android, appium, element, appium-android

I tried many times to locate an element in inputbox, but always be told there was something wrong so failed. How can I find the reason why?

params: Android, appium, python.

Codes as follows:

```
time.sleep(2)
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='android.widget.EditText'and 
@index='0']").send_keys("XXXXX")
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='android.widget.EditText'][1]").send_keys("XXXXX")
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@text='login']").click()
```

Results:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\unittest\case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "C:\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\unittest\case.py", line 601, in run
    testMethod()
  File "D:\XXXXX\login.py", line 33, in testchangeto_pageone
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='android.widget.EditText'and @index='0']").send_keys("xxxx")
  File "C:\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "C:\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\errorhandler.py", line 29, in check_response
    raise wde
  File "C:\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\errorhandler.py", line 24, in check_response
    super(MobileErrorHandler, self).check_response(response)
  File "C:\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Message: Cannot set the element to 'xxxxxx'. Did you interact with the correct element?
```

[element in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ligOb.png)

Comment: Please refrain from begging and pleading when asking for help from volunteers, both here on Stack Overflow and elsewhere. It is better to state the problem calmly and succinctly, and to try not to infer that your distress is the fault of a volunteer who does not help.

Comment: Instead of begging, Please check answer and let us know. It can helpful for others too.

Answer (score 1):

Your xpath is wrong. For your information, attached image is also wrong. you should have to locate editText while you are showing imageView in attached screenshot.

Try with below Xpath.

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@index='0']").send_keys("XXXXX")
```

**Another textbox:**

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@index='1']").send_keys("XXXXX")
```